# What does this particular bessel with a superscript and ordered pair mean?

Tags: calculus, integration, bessel-functions

I was evaluating this on [WolframAlpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WolframAlpha): https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5Bcos%5C%2840%292%CF%80%5C%2840%29Divide%5B1%2Cx%5D%2B1x%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%2Cx%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D

And the following function [image: BesselJ^(1,0) (0, 4pi)]

appears. Are there some resources on what this function is? I've looked through the Wolfram documentation, but I couldn't find it. I tried to type it into WolframAlpha, and ChatGPT was useless.

Comment: In the notation of Mathematica and Wolfram Research, if $F:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$, $F^{(a_1,\dots,a_n)}$ is taken to mean $$\frac{\partial^{a_1+\dots+a_n}F}{{\partial x_1}^{a_1}\dots{\partial x_n}^{a_n}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following integral in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik's [Table of Integrals, Series, and Products](http://fisica.ciens.ucv.ve/%7Esvincenz/TISPISGIMR.pdf) (p. 480, formula 3.868.2):
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\cos\left(a^2x+\frac{b^2}{x}\right)\frac{dx}{x}=-\pi Y_0(2ab)\qquad[a>0, b>0], \tag{1}
$$
where $Y_0$ is the Bessel function of the second kind and order zero.
When $a=b=\sqrt{2\pi}$, Eq. $(1)$ reduces to your integral:
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\cos\left(2\pi\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)\frac{dx}{x}=-\pi Y_0(4\pi). \tag{2}
$$
Therefore, apparently $\text{BesselJ}^{(1,0)}(0,x)=\frac{\pi}{2}Y_0(x)$.

Answer (score 6):

Superscript $(1,0)$ means derivative with respect to the first variable in Wolfram's notation. Here $\mathrm{BesselJ}(\nu,z)$ is a funcion of two arguments, where $\nu$ is the order, so
$\mathrm{BesselJ^{(1,0)}}(\nu,z)$ = $\frac{\partial}{\partial \nu}J_{\nu}(z)$. Hence, $$\mathrm{BesselJ^{(1,0)}}(0, 4\pi) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \nu}J_{\nu}(4\pi)\Big|_{\nu=0}$$

According to [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.15) (eq. 10.15.3),
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \nu}J_\nu(z)\Big|_{\nu=n} = 
\frac{\pi}{2} Y_n(z) + \frac{n!}{2\left(z/2\right)^n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\left(z/2\right)^k J_k(z)}{k!(n-k)},
$$
where $Y_n$ is the Bessel Function of the Second Kind. So, for $\nu = 0$:
$\frac{\partial}{\partial \nu}J_{\nu}(z)\Big|_{\nu=0} = \frac{\pi}{2} Y_0(z)$.